# Can someone help me derive the following matrices?

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, computer-science, fluid-dynamics

The matrices highlighted in Yellow are the matrices I don't understand how to find.

[image: paper]

What I don't understand is how the matrices in the picture are found. The equations below are the the equations I am trying to get into the form like the picture.

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}
 + \frac{\partial F_c}{\partial x}
 + \frac{\partial G_c}{\partial y} = S_v
$$

Where
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix} \rho \\ \rho u \\ \rho v \\ \rho E  \end{pmatrix},
F_c = \begin{pmatrix} \rho u \\ \rho u^2 + p \\ \rho vu \\ (\rho E + p)u   \end{pmatrix},
G_c = \begin{pmatrix} \rho v \\ \rho uv \\ \rho v^2 + p \\ (\rho E + p)v   \end{pmatrix}
$$

We can ignore the $S_v$ term. What I don't understand is how to get what is in the picture. I hope this is enough to help me.

The characteristic form is
$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$ + F$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ + G$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$ = $S_v$

where
$$
F = \begin{pmatrix} u&{\rho}&0&0 \\ 0&u&0&1/{\rho} \\ 0&0&u&0 \\ 0&{\rho}c^2&0&u \end{pmatrix},
G = \begin{pmatrix} v&0&{\rho}&0 \\ 0&v&0&0 \\ 0&0&v&1/{\rho} \\ 0&0&{\rho}c^2&v \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There's probably some conservation laws causing terms to cancel.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't even know how I set up the matrix to even begin the process of finding F or G. Can you please help me?

Comment: I suggest removing the algebra tags, and adding fluid dynamics, because this is mostly a physics question. You can see that the energy per mass, E, has disappeared and pressure,p, has entered the fourth equation, which has to involve physical properties of the fluid that you should probably state, and that have nothing to do with mathematics. Once you have that clear, plain calculus will transform the equation for you.